# CSS3 transform rotate images in flex layout with equal gutters

Tags: css, rotation, flexbox, css-transforms

I'm trying to rotate images by 30 degrees and maintain equal margins between.

The desired result looks like a brick layout:
[image]

I am starting out with a wrapped flex layout:

[image]

And adding a 30deg rotation:

[image]

But notice the unevenness.

Here's the CSS:

```
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;

  .img-item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    @media #{$tablet} { & { flex: 0 0 25%; } }
    @media #{$desktop} { & { flex: 0 0 20%; } }

    /** padding for the gutters when using flexbox **/
    padding: 5px 10px;
    /** Transformation here
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);

    /* chop off according to media queries - based off of 15 results*/
    &:last-child {
      display: none;
    }
    &:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
      @media #{$tablet} { & { display: none; } }
      @media #{$desktop} { & { display: initial; } }
    }

    .img {
      object-fit: contain;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-item">
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
      <img class="img" src="http://www.logos.com/media/pbb/SampleCover.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>=
```

I tried using CSS grids too, but had similar lack of interlocking brick layout and same vertical gutters and lack of horizontal gutters.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: When using `transform: rotate` it only visually rotate the images, so the DOM have no idea they moved, hence still think they are properly aligned.

Comment: Also, if you make your code run in a fiddle or codepen (or compile its styles to CSS so it can run in a Stack snippet), you most likely will get a proper suggestion what can be done

Comment: It would also be good to know _how_ they should align after the rotation, and a drawing of that is a great way to show it.

Comment: After rotation is first image -- rotated at 30deg.